# Lint c# before commit with omnisharp & roslyn?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, lint, omnisharp

I have VS Code workspace with c# projects. I want to configre code style to work within team. I tried to use `omnisharp`, `roslyn` and `.editorconfig`, but seems like it is too hard to set up rules and i didn't find way to lint before commit.
What is the best way to do it?
UPD. I found that some rules could be applied through analyzers, but are there more  flexible tools?

Comment: Found this. You should be able to run dotnet commands through npm with dotnet tools. 

https://www.danilucaci.com/blog/how-to-lint-and-test-code-using-git-pre-commit-hooks